# Intellij IDEA autoclose HTML tags, how do I disable it?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I am editing an HTML file and open a tag for example `<td>` it will automatically add the closing tag `</td>` right after it.

I find this intensely irritating 98% of the time and only slightly useful the remaining 2% but I cannot figure out how to switch it off.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Navigate to Settings->Editor->Smart Keys

Uncheck "Automatically Insert Closing Tag" in the XML/HTML section.

**In IntelliJ 15+, this has moved here (thanks @Philihp Busby)**:

Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> "Insert closing tag on tag completion"

Comment: too bad they aren't actually smart, then they wouldn't be so annoying that you want to disable them...

Comment: Not working in IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.2.4 but holding down option key and pressing space will prevent the smart key logic from happening

Answer (score 5):

This has changed, and is now Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys

Answer (score 2):

For My IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 it is in:

```
File->Settings(ctrl+alt+s)->Editor->General->Smart Keys->
Javadoc->checkbox "Automatically insert closing tag"
```